# Change class on click based on current class

Tags: jquery, click, font-awesome, addclass, removeclass

I want to take a simple FontAwesome icon:

```
<div class="emotion">
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
</div>
```

and swap the class depending on what the current class is:

```
$(".emotion .fa-smile-o").click(function (){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-smile-o').addClass("fa-meh-o");
});
$(".emotion .fa-meh-o").click(function (){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-meh-o').addClass("fa-frown-o");
});
$(".emotion .fa-frown-o").click(function (){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-frown-o').addClass("fa-smile-o");
});
```

But currently this only works for the first class change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing is, when these binders run those classes are not on the element you asking for. so the only first one works because it is already that class when these code did run.

so to take care of it you should do it like this:

```
$(".emotion .fa").click(function (){
    if($(this).hasClass('fa-smile-o')) {
       $(this).removeClass('fa-smile-o').addClass("fa-frown-o");
       return;
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('fa-meh-o')) {
       $(this).removeClass('fa-meh-o').addClass("fa-frown-o");
       return;
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('fa-frown-o')) {
       $(this).removeClass('fa-frown-o').addClass("fa-smile-o");
       return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), because when you add click events, on the page, there are not elements with classes `.fa-frown-o` and `.fa-meh-o`

```
$(".emotion").on('click', '.fa-smile-o', function (){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-smile-o').addClass("fa-frown-o");
});
$(".emotion").on('click', '.fa-meh-o', function (){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-meh-o').addClass("fa-frown-o");
});
$(".emotion").on('click', '.fa-frown-o', function (){
    $(this).removeClass('fa-frown-o').addClass("fa-smile-o");
});
```